# “Cannot GET /” when trying to connect to localhost:31416 in node.js

Tags: iot

This code is an API that makes use of the automated control panel with the aim of synchronizing the functionalities of IoT applications, I am trying to compile and open it on localhost and i need help to fix this.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

// Netbeast apps need to accept the port to be launched by parameters
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2))

app.use(express.static('public'))

var server = app.listen(argv.port || 31416, function () {
var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port
console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
})
```